# How to merge two list without sorting on this link below?

Tags: c, merge, linked-list

This code shows the output of the sorted list but I want an unsorted list. Can anyone help me, please? Can anyone tell me where the code is sorted? I can't find it. I just need to merge these two lists. List one first then list2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} *LLOne, *LLTwo, *mergedLL;

void initialize(){
    LLOne = LLTwo = mergedLL = NULL;
}


void insert(struct node **head, int num) {

    struct node* newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data  = num;

    newNode->next = *head;

    *head = newNode;
    printf("Inserted Element : %d\n", num);
}

struct node* mergeLinkedList(struct node* LLTwo, struct node* LLOne){
    struct node *resultHead, *resultTail, *temp;
    resultHead = resultTail = NULL;
    while(1){
        /* */
        if(LLOne == NULL){
            resultTail->next = LLTwo;
            break;
        }

        if(LLTwo == NULL) {
            resultTail->next = LLOne;
            break;
        }


        if(LLOne->data <= LLTwo->data){
            temp = LLOne;
            LLOne = LLOne->next;
        } else {
            temp = LLTwo;
            LLTwo = LLTwo->next;
        }

        if(resultHead == NULL){
            resultHead = resultTail = temp;
        } else {
            resultTail->next = temp;
            resultTail = temp;
        }
        resultTail->next = NULL;
    }

    return resultHead;
}


void printLinkedList(struct node *nodePtr) {
  while (nodePtr != NULL) {
     printf("%d", nodePtr->data);
     nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
     if(nodePtr != NULL)
         printf("-->");
  }
}

int main() {
    initialize();
    insert(&LLOne, 2);
    insert(&LLOne, 4);
    insert(&LLOne, 7);
    insert(&LLOne, 8);
    insert(&LLOne, 10);
    printLinkedList(LLOne);
    printf("\n");
    insert(&LLTwo, 3);
    insert(&LLTwo, 5);
    insert(&LLTwo, 9);
    insert(&LLTwo, 11);
    insert(&LLTwo, 15);
    printLinkedList(LLTwo);

    mergedLL = mergeLinkedList(LLTwo, LLOne);
    printf("\nMerged Linked List\n");
    printLinkedList(mergedLL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at this line: `if(LLOne->data <= LLTwo->data)`

Comment: how can i solve this?

Comment: Why not just call `insert` to add all nodes from both lists into the merge list? First copy from the first list, then the second list.

Comment: For a minimal change: You always want the `if` part. Just remove the `if() {} else {}`and do `temp = LLOne; LLOne = LLOne->next;` For a good solution: Rewrite the whole function as it is not made for this task. It is made for merging, not for concatenating.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating two lists has little to do with merging sorted lists. The code you are looking for is much simpler than the merge algorithm. In essence you need to only set one `next` link so that the tail of the first list links to the head of the second list:

```
struct node* tail(struct node* head) {
    if (head != NULL) {
        while (head->next != NULL) {
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

struct node* mergeLinkedList(struct node* LLOne, struct node* LLTwo){
    if (LLOne == NULL) return LLTwo;
    tail(LLOne)->next = LLTwo;
    return LLOne;
}
```

Note that I changed the order of the parameters. I found it a bit confusing that you had them in reverse order (`LLTwo` and then `LLOne`). So in `main` you should make the call like this:

```
mergedLL = mergeLinkedList(LLOne, LLTwo);
```

Be aware that concatenating lists like this will *mutate* the first list (if it was not empty). So if you would print `LLOne` after this call, you will actually see the concatenated list. The same was true for your original merge function.

If you would want to avoid this mutation, then you need to create a new node for each node that is in the first list, and only set the `next` link of the *new* tail.

Comment: How merge function work on this code? Can you help me?